# Insert zeroes between elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following Array 
`a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6])`
now I have to add 2/12/22 zeros to add it to a Matrix with 10/20/30 columns.

It should look like that:
`a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6])` -> 
`a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6])`

Im using `np.pad` to fill with zeros on the borders of an array, but is there a way to do it the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine the [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) function with the slicing of the original matrix, so you can stack the beginning of the matrix, the zeroes, and the remaining of the matrix:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6])
result = np.hstack((a[0:4], np.zeros(12), a[4:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mission for `numpy.insert` function, example (2 zeros):

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6])
a = np.insert(a,4,np.zeros(2))
print(a) #prints [1 2 3 4 0 0 9 8 7 6]
```

Explanation: you can read that `insert` as: get array `a`, add beyond `4`th element: `2 zeros`.